# How to find finger print Touch Id count?

Tags: ios

Is there any way to find out how many  finger print Touch Id Register in iPhone5s device onwards?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand in the documentation, developers do not have access to fingerprint data or any thing besides using it as authentication. So, no.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Apple documentation for LAContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/LAContext/canEvaluatePolicy:error:), It states,

> Authentication contexts are used to evaluate authentication policies, allowing apps to request the user to authenticate themselves using personal information such as a fingerprint registered with Touch ID.

It have only two methods,

```
- canEvaluatePolicy:error:
```

and

```
- evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:
```

and none of them gives that how many touch ids registers with it.

You should also refer 
[Local Authentication Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/)